# удаление файлов по шаблону

Tags: linux, bash

Есть дерево дерево каталогов:

```
`/folder/subfolder/.../.../logs/`
```

Т.е. в `subfolder` есть проект, в проекте есть подпроект, а в каждом проекте есть `/logs/`, где лежит куча файлов логов нескольких типов:

```
filetype1.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
filetype2.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
filetype3.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
filetype4.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
```

нужно оставить только 15 последних файлов каждого типа.

Я знаю как сделать эту задачу циклом-в-цикле, но мне это не нравится. Должен же быть способ решить это нормально средствами bash

Comment: вот для таких задач и была когда-то написана замечательная программа logrotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не подзакладываясь на чудные имена, считая, что `sort -g` корректно определит «последние» и что `filetype` не содержит точек можно как-то так:

```
find -type d -name logs | while read d; do 
  find "$d" -type f -name '*.log' | sed -e 's!.*/!!;s!\..*!!' | sort -u | \
    while read type; do
      find "$d" -type f -name "$type*.log" | sort -g | head -n -15 | xargs rm -i
    done
done
```

ключ `-i` у `rm`'а после отладки можно будет убрать...

Comment: это намного лучше, чем то, что я наваял))), но в месте `head -n -15` отрабатывает не так как нужно. он отсекает не по каждому типу файлов, а из всего списка файлов

Comment: поправил... сначала очитался... с таким условием несколько посложней получилось...

Comment: вчера на основе первой версии переделал свой скрипт и все получилось. Новая версия работает как нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Должно помочь:

`find /folder/subfolder/ -mindepth 3 -type f -mtime +1 -name '*.log*' -not -regex '.*\([a-z]\(1\|2\|3\|4\|5\|6\|7\|8\|9\|10\|11\|12\|13\|14\|15\)\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*'`

По ключам:

`-mindepth 3` -минимальный уровень вложения файлов, по задаче это 3 каталог

`-type f` -только файлы

`-mtime +1` - файлы старше 1-го дня, что бы не затереть текущий лог без цифр

`-name '*.log*'` - маска имени файла

`-not` - отрицание следующего выражения

`-regex '.*\([a-z]\(1\|2\|3\|4\|5\|6\|7\|8\|9\|10\|11\|12\|13\|14\|15\)\.[1-2][1-2][0-9][0-9]\).*'` -шаблон имени файла, `[a-z]` любая буква, за ней цифры от 1 до 15, после точка и `[1-2][1-2][0-9][0-9]` 4 цифры года.

Писал по памяти, протестировать сейчас негде, если после теста все ок, добавить в конце `-exec rm -f {} \;` - это удалит все найденные файлы.